# Object initializer syntax confusion. Using parentheses in initializer?

Tags: c#, object-initializers

So I was looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to understand how to use an object initializer, be it for anonymous types or not. The only thing that I would like to find out is why(and if it matters) is there a difference in the example.

It goes like this: for a Cat

```
class Cat
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can see the first example like so:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

This makes sense. But then, you can find the following:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
    new Cat(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 }
};
```

Now my question is: (why) is there a difference between `new Cat{...}`
and `new Cat(){...}` ?
Why should we use(or not) the parentheses?

Comment: I wish such "optimizations" of a language should take a time to consider the balance between advantages -- spares you from adding `()` -- and disadvantages -- the confusion and all fuss it draws plus a new rule to remember that you can only use this syntactic candy when the class has a parameterless constructor. As a side note, in C++ it has a purpose: zero initialization vs indeterminate value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an object has a *parameterless constructor*, you can omit the parentheses. So both of these are valid

```
// Assuming cat has a constructor with no parameters
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
Cat cat = new Cat() { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

The `List<T>` itself has an object initializer where you can provide any number of items, and they are automatically added to the collection.

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>()
{
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 }, // Add sylvester to the List
    new Cat(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 } // And Whiskers too
};
```

As mentioned above you can also remove the parentheses here aswell

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat { Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 }, // Add sylvester to the List
    new Cat { Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 } // And Whiskers too
};
```

Comment: I think your reference to the parameterless constructor (name) was pretty important, since it's used to specify error messages in different libraries like EF

Comment: @Jamiec , it seems that this is the part I was missing: *If an object has a no parameter constructor, you can omit the parentheses*

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, can you elaborate a bit on what you've just pointed?

Comment: @bgiuga A constructor that takes no parameters is called a *parameterless constructor*. It's important to know the name because there are libraries that refer explicitly to them when throwing error messages

Answer (score 6):

These are just two acceptable equivalent syntax for instantiation of objects in C# *with object initialization* (you can't omit the parenthesis if you are just doing `var cat = new Cat();`).

- since your class has no explicit constructor, a default parameter-less constructor is provided to the Cat class
- `new Cat {...}` allows to instantiate *and initialize properties of* the Cat object as a shortcut for `new Cat() {...}`, calling the mentioned constructor.

The part about the constructor is important. If there is no implicit default constructor / explicit parameter-less constructor, then you cannot omit the parenthesis, and you'll have to provide parameters in them anyway :

```
public class Cat {
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public Cat(string s) { // since I provide a constructor with parameter here, no parameterless constructor exists
        Name = s; 
    } 
}

// ...
void TestCat() 
{

    // compilation error : 'Cat'' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
    //var badCat1 = new Cat { Name = "Felix", Age = 3} ;
    //var badCat2 = new Cat() { Name = "Felix", Age = 3} ;

    // works (but no way to remove parenthesis here, since there are parameters to pass to csontructor)
    var goodCat = new Cat("Felix") { Age = 3 } ;

    Console.WriteLine($"The cat {goodCat.Name} is {goodCat.Age} years old");
}
```

---

**Special case** : (which is used a lot for collections, list, dictionaries, etc...).

If a class T implements IEnumerable (i.e. has a IEnumerable 
 GetEnumerator() public function), and implements an Add method, then the object initializer *will use the Add method* with the collection on enumeration.

Example from https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/26/fun-with-custom-c-collection-initializers

Creation of special class "Points" which acts like a "List" with the initialization.

Note that this also uses the existing parameter-less constructor !

```
public class Points : IEnumerable<Point3D>
{
    private readonly List<Point3D> _points;

    public Points()
    {
        _points = new List<Point3D>();
    }

    public void Add(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        _points.Add(new Point3D(x, y, z));
    }

    public IEnumerator<Point3D> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _points.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Used like that :

```
var cube = new Points
{
    { -1, -1, -1 },
    { -1, -1,  1 },
    { -1,  1, -1 },
    { -1,  1,  1 },
    {  1, -1, -1 },
    {  1, -1,  1 },
    {  1,  1, -1 },
    {  1,  1,  1 }
};
```

Comment: For any downvoter, please explain how this is wrong, so I can improve and/or delete my answer.

Comment: You might want to go a bit more into detail regarding the questions at the bottom: *"(why) is there a difference between new Cat{...} and new Cat(){...} ? Why should we use(or not) the parentheses?"*

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer thanks for your input. I added more details, and trying not to be too redundant with the other accepted answer.

Comment: Upvoted, for mentioning what's behind the scenes for the collections initializers